# Is it possible to revert to older version of Dymola? Is parameter sweep behaving different in Dymola 2021?

Tags: version, dymola

I have recently renewed the license of Dymola and I received access to Dymola 2021. I believe that there are some changes in `parameter sweep`. the point is that I used to sweep parameters of my model conveniently with older version, but now I receive the following error:

> setting ParameterName has no effect in model.
>   After translation you can only set literal start-values and non evaluated parameters.

I would appreciate if someone could advise.

Comment: You can install multiple Dymola versions and just use the previous one. But if you had to apply library conversion scripts on your models, this can make troubles. Do you have a minimal example for your problem?

Comment: @marco Thanks for your reply. I am working on "stratified" tank model of Buildings library. There is a "time constant for mixing" called "tau" which is a parameter used to induce buoyancy effects. I used to sweep this parameter to monitor the results of temperature gradients along the tank, but with new version I am not able to do so. Would you like me to enter the code as well? Additionally, would you please let me know how to install multiple versions of Dymola?

Comment: "Enter code as well?": Yes, a minimal reproducible example should be provided (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you commented on Markus his answer is going into that direction... 
Old Dymola versions: Get the installer from your reseller and install it.

Comment: @marco I got your point. Thanks for your comment and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult to judge without the actual code. The reason could be, that the new Dymola version evaluates other parameters than the old one does. Instead of reverting to an older version of Dymola you could try this:

The solution could be to force Dymola to not evaluate the parameter you want to sweep. This can be done by adding `annotation(Evaluate=false)` to the parameter that shall be changed during the sweep.

Comment: The parameter "tau" is the one that I can't sweep.                      Buildings.Fluid.Storage.Stratified simTan(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
      TFlu_start={327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74,
          327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74,327.74}, T_start(displayUnit = "K"), VTan = 2, dIns = 0.1, hTan = 1.77, m_flow_nominal = 0.1, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial, nSeg = 30,
      tau=3600)

Comment: Then it should help to go to `Buildings.Fluid.Storage.BaseClasses.PartialStratified` and change from `parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time tau=1 "Time constant for mixing";` to `parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time tau=1 "Time constant for mixing" annotation(Evaluate=false);`

Comment: Dear Markus, I really appreciate your reply and help. It works properly like before.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by @MarkusA I would like to add that downgrading due to this specific warning is not a good idea.

Apart from changes in evaluation of parameters the main change in Dymola 2021 is that the warning was added to sweep parameter, whereas previously the sweep could produce constant output without any warning.